# Actualizar un campo con Livewire

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Estoy tratando de actualizar sólamente un valor de mi modelo objeto que se llama Categorías, tratando de actualizar sólo "name", y mediante este método estoy intenado llevar esta acción a cabo pero al momento de querer mandar la información en la página no sucede nada.

Lo siguiente es mi componente clase de Livewire:

```
 // Categories
    public Category $category;

    public $name;
    public $description;
    public $categorySuccess;
    public $categoryUpdated;
    public $categoryDeleted;

    protected $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'description' => 'min:5'
    ];

    public function updateCategory(Category $category)
    {           
        $this->validate();

        Category::find($this->category->id)->update($category);
        
        $this->categoryUpdated = 'Tu categoría ha sido actualizada.';
    }
```

Este es mi formulario (sin incluir el otro formulario de crear, ver más abajo para ver toda la estructura)

```
<x-slot name="index">
    @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <form
            wire:submit.prevent="updateCategory"
            class="mt-6 flex flex-col items-center justify-center md:flex-row md:space-x-2 p-4 hover:bg-gray-200 active:bg-green-700 transition ease-in-out"
        >
            <input
                class="text-sm w-56"
                type="text"
                name="name"
                id="name"
                value="{{ $category->name }}"
            >

            <div class="mt-2 md:mt-0">
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="md:bg-gray-500 bg-blue-500 text-white text-sm p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-500 transition ease-in-out"
                >   
                    Actualizar
                </button>

                <button 
                    wire:click="deleteCategory({{ $category->id }})"
                    class="md:bg-gray-500 bg-red-500 text-white text-sm p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-red-500 transition ease-in-out"
                >
                    Borrar
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
    @endforeach
</x-slot>
```

Tengo que utilizar `wire:model` en el input que estoy tratando de actualizar? Porque por el momento cuando pongo esta propiedad, lo que pasa es que el valor en la caja de texto desaparece.

Tabs; para actualizar y/ó borrar y registrar nueva categoría.

```
<x-faro-modal hash="category-crud-modal" type="categories">
    <x-category-tabs>

        <x-slot name="tabLinks">
            <button 
                class="border rounded-bl-none border-b-0 rounded-br-none border-blue-500 p-2 w-24 md:w-32 rounded-xl hover:bg-gray-200 transition ease-in-out"
                :class="{'bg-gray-200' : currentTab === 'index'}"
                x-on:click="currentTab = 'index'"
            >
                Categorías
            </button>

            <button 
                class="border rounded-bl-none border-b-0 rounded-br-none border-blue-500 p-2 w-24 md:w-32 rounded-xl hover:bg-gray-200 transition ease-in-out"
                :class="{'bg-gray-200' : currentTab === 'create'}"
                x-on:click="currentTab = 'create'"
            >
                Crear
            </button>
        </x-slot>
        
        <x-slot name="index">
            @if ($categoryUpdated)
                <div class="text-sm p-4 bg-blue-200 rounded-md w-full h-8 mt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                    {{ $categoryUpdated }}
                    <button 
                        type="button" 
                        wire:click="$set('categoryUpdated', null)" 
                        class="cursor-pointer text-xl relative right-0 hover:text-white transition ease-in-out"
                    >
                        &times;
                    </button>
                </div>
            @endif

            @if ($categoryDeleted)
                <div class="text-sm p-4 bg-yellow-200 rounded-md w-full h-8 mt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                    {{ $categoryDeleted}}
                    <button 
                        type="button" 
                        wire:click="$set('categoryDeleted', null)" 
                        class="cursor-pointer text-xl relative right-0 hover:text-white transition ease-in-out"
                    >
                        &times;
                    </button>
                </div>
            @endif

            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                <div class="mt-6 flex flex-col items-center justify-center md:flex-row md:space-x-2 p-4 hover:bg-gray-200 active:bg-green-700 transition ease-in-out">
                    <input
                        class="text-sm w-56"
                        type="text"
                        name="name"
                        id="name"
                        value="{{ $category->name }}"
                    >

                    <div class="mt-2 md:mt-0">
                        <button
                            wire:click="update({{ $category->id }})"
                            type="submit"
                            class="md:bg-gray-500 bg-blue-500 text-white text-sm p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-blue-500 transition ease-in-out"
                        >   
                            Actualizar
                        </button>

                        <button 
                            wire:click="deleteCategory({{ $category->id }})"
                            class="md:bg-gray-500 bg-red-500 text-white text-sm p-2 rounded-md hover:bg-red-500 transition ease-in-out"
                        >
                            Borrar
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </x-slot>

        <x-slot name="create">
            <div>
                @if ( $categorySuccess)
                    <div class="text-sm p-4 bg-green-200 rounded-md w-full h-8 mt-4 flex items-center justify-between">
                        {{ $categorySuccess }}
                        <button 
                            type="button" 
                            wire:click="$set('categorySuccess', null)" 
                            class="cursor-pointer text-xl relative right-0 hover:text-white transition ease-in-out"
                        >
                            &times;
                        </button>
                    </div>
                @endif
            </div>
            
                <form
                    class="mt-6 flex flex-col p-4 space-y-4"
                    wire:submit.prevent="submitCategory"
                    action="#"
                    method="POST"
                >
                <label 
                    class="font-semibold"
                    for="name">
                    Nombre de categoría
                </label>

                <input 
                    wire:model="name"
                    class="@error('name') border border-red-500 @enderror w-full"
                    type="text"
                    name="name"
                    id="name"
                    value="{{ old('name') }}"
                    required
                >
                <div>
                    @error('name')
                        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>

                <label 
                    class="font-semibold"
                    for="description">
                    Breve descripción
                </label>
                <textarea 
                    wire:model="description"
                    name="description" 
                    id="description" 
                    class="@error('description') border border-red-500 @enderror resize-none"
                    rows="2"
                    value="{{ old('description') }}"
                > </textarea>

                <div>
                    @error('description')
                        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
                    @enderror
                </div>

                <button 
                    class="bg-green-500 rounded-md p-2 hover:bg-green-700 hover:text-white transition ease-in-out"
                    type="submit"
                >
                    Guardar
                </button>
            </form>
        </x-slot>

    </x-category-tabs>
</x-faro-modal>
```

Componente Blade que aloja contenido que se acomoda en el modal llamado `category-tabs`

```
<div class="h-full w-full p-4">
    <div x-data="{currentTab: 'index'}" class="h-auto flex flex-col items-center justify-center mt-8">
        
        <div class="w-full text-center">
            {{$tabLinks}}
        </div>

        <div 
            x-show="currentTab === 'index'" 
            class="flex flex-col w-full"
        >
            {{$index}}
        </div>

        <div 
            x-show="currentTab === 'create'" 
            class="flex flex-col w-full"
        >
            {{$create}}
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Estás listando todos los registros en la misma página donde los actualizarás?

Comment: En síntesis estoy utilizando "tabs" y en un tab tengo la lista que muestra todas las categorías, aquí puedo borrar categorías y es aquí mismo donde quiero actualizar la misma mediante un botón. En la otra tab se pueden dar de alta nuevas categorías. Estoy listando ambas "tabs" mediante 2 slots, provenientes de un mismo componente Blade. Actualizaré la pregunta para que puedas ver eso. Saludos.